# When typing a date into cell as 12/24, parse it as Dec 1 2024, instead of Dec 24, 2020. (dd/dd to Month Year rather then Month Day)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Going to a new cell, if I type `07/22`, if the column data format is set to a date, it interprets this to `July 22, 2020` (where `2020` is the current year).  I want it to use the `22` as the year, I don't mind if behind the scenes it translates to `July 1, 2022` or `July 31, 2022` (although I prefer the 1st).

I have the data column set to `Month (08)/Year (30)` i.e. expected output is exactly as typed `07/22`.  But even with this on, Sheets interprets the entry as Month, Day.

Comment: What is the locale of your spreadsheet?

Comment: United States / (GMT-05:00)

Comment: @marikamitsos has covered the non-negotiable aspects of date entry in Google Sheets. You have not explained the layout of your spreadsheet, but a possible option might be to use a formula along the lines of `=date(2022,month(C6),1)` (where cell C6 contains the `7/22` "date" that you entered). If this formula is formatted as Month/Year, it will display "7/22".

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...if I type 07/22, if the column data format is set to a date, it interprets this to July 22, 2020 (where 2020 is the current year).

**The behaviour cannot be changed.**

> I don't mind if behind the scenes it translates to July 1, 2022 or July 31, 2022

**That is what you need to write as well.**

> I have the data column set to Month (08)/Year (30) i.e. expected output is exactly as typed 07/22. But even with this on, Sheets interprets the entry as Month, Day.

**This is just the formatting.**
You still have to write a date as `day/month/year` or `month/day/year` pending on your locale.

*("When typing a date into cell as 12/24". Just think that this could be interpreted as hours, as a fraction etc...)*

Comment: Just to be clear, a user should enter `01/07/22` and format the cell as Month/Year.

Comment: @Tedinoz To be clearer *"a date as `day/month/year` or `month/day/year` pending on your locale"*. I am saying that because one could also write `01-07-22` and Google will still understand a date.

Comment: “because one could also write 01-07-22 and Google will still understand a date. ” Indeed, an important distinction. Thank you.

Comment: Well I guess an answer I don't want to hear is still a correct answer.  Thank you.